# Evaluation of k-means clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means, sentiment-analysis

I'm doing a project about twitter users sentiment analysis right now. I'm using K-Means algorithm to cluster the tweets into 3 clusters, positive, negative and neutral. But I'm still confused about the evaluation in my project. Do you guys have any recommendation of what method or algorithm that I should use to evaluate the cluster or the performance of my sentiment analysis? 
Sorry for my poor English.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use an *unsupervised* approach like k-means for a *supervised* problem like sentiment analysis.

The chances that the clusters found by k-means correspond to sentiments is almost 0. More likely, the clusters will correspond to languages or length.

Wrong tool for this problem.